# Read Log file through batch untill Keyword "Terminate" is found

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am new to batch programming and I am executing a windows batch command through jenkins on the target Windows machine. 
My requirement is to read the log file ( aut.log ) while the automation is running. Once keyword "Terminate' is written in the log file, it should stop reading log and proceed to the next step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to give an answer based on the very unclear question.

```
@echo off
:start
FIND /C /I "Terminate" "F:\aut.log"
IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0 (echo found word Terminate
) else (
  goto start
)
```

This will do a find in the file for the word `Terminate` in a loop until it is found and then echo `found word Terminate` at this point you will replace the echo command with your command. if however the word is not found, it will return to to `:start` to try again and continue forever until the word is found.

If you want to slow down the process, below :start, add `timeout /t 1` for a 1 second time out.

```
@echo off
:start
timeout /t 1
FIND /C /I "Terminate" "F:\aut.log"
IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0 (echo found word Terminate
) else (
  goto start
)
```

Finally, if you do not want to see the actual output on screen of the loop while running, you can push output to null with `1>null`

```
@echo off
:start
FIND /C /I "Terminate" "F:\aut.log" 1>null
IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0 (echo found word Terminate
) else (
  goto start:
)
```

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. But the question statement understood is correct. I want to keep searching for the word "Terminate" in aut.log untill word terminate is written by the automation script into this file. Aut.log is continously being written with automation logs and once the automation ends, Terminate is written at the end of log file. I ran your code but it not running the loop forever

Comment: @kamalpamnani can you add the output of the script to you question? It must loop, unless it found the word terminate. Copy the code as is, create a new batchfile with a extention of `.cmd` and paste the code in there. Ensure that the path to the log file is correct, make sure that the double quotes around the path to file is there as well.